# sharing data from ipad to mac using tcp/ip 

Tags: iphone

In my project I have to share files between ipad and mac with the use of Tcp/ip .

Can any one help ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in reading the documentation about [Bonjour](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Articles/about.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002458-SW1), an open protocol for zero-configuration networking over IP.

Then if you have a more specific question, we might help you with... a more specific answer.

Comment: ya As i am new to the app development ,  my Question is  using IP address and port num. i have to send a text from ipad to mac and mac to ipad , can u please explain it .......... as i was struck for this in my project...